# Flex: when to create a custom component and when to create a skin?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4.6

I don't see the difference between both cases. It began when I wanted to have some special list (e.g. with some navigation or title on the top). But then I didn't know what to do, should I extend List and override some methods, or should I simply create a skin for the existing List component?
thnx

Answer (score 1):

If you're just looking for visual modifications, you should most likely just skin the component.

Creating a custom component, that `extends List`, or using composition would suggest that you need some additional functionality that `List` itself do not provide to serve your purpose. If the case is the latter, then you should use inheritance or composition.

Comment: If I am going to add a component to another component (e.g. If I want to add my own button with some functionality at the top of a List), wouldn't this be a composite component? i.e. why not then creating a composite component by extending "List" class?